# System.Diagnostics.Trace on a live environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, trace, system.diagnostics

Problems have been reported to me regarding the performance of a live site. I can't seem to replicate any of these issues on any dev or staging environments, and the profilers I have ran against dev has revealed nothing unusual.

This has led me to turn to a diagnostics trace for a simple timing trace so I can at least try and isolate the cause and try and narrow it down.

I'm quite happy to add

`System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("....");`

wherever necessary and add a listener (via web.config entry) to write out to a log file, but could this massively impact the performance of the live environment itself?

Is there anything else I need to consider when, potentially, leaving this to run over the weekend? i.e. is it best that I specify how large the log file is to get before closing and opening a new one?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how much data you are going to log so turn on the logger and check if your application behaves normally. Also if logging to a log file slows down your application consider a faster TraceListener such as EventLogTraceListener (you may create a dedicated event log for this purpose with maximum size and log rolling). In case logging to a file is not a problem get [EssentialDiagnostics](https://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com) `RollingFileTraceListener`. It has many options including setting maximum file size and the number of rolled files.

Answer (score -1):

Use a logging framework like log4NET and make logging like:

```
LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Debug("...");
```

When you disable logging afterwards in the configuration, these functions are not executed by the framework.

If you need to do string formatting for your messages: Use "DebugFormat()"  which will not do the formatting if it is not needed by the level of logging desired.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's ideal if you are concerned about the performance if you leave it in there.  It's much more flexible then simple tracing.

Comment: I didnt downvote, but you're bot answering to OP's concern about performance. You should add that log4net use a buffer to lessen that impact and allows to cap size.